# Возврат значений во время Ajax-запроса

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Уважаемые посетители, столкнулся со сложностью, нуждаюсь в Вашей помощи.

**Суть вопроса:**

- При отработке ajax-запроса подгружается много информации из php;
- Для видимости загрузки сделал preloader страницы, но сейчас решил делать progressbar с отображением значения %% загрузки / количества переданных байт, неважно;
- Значения прогресса думал получать в цикле и выводить в контейнер с определенным ид / классом.

**Суть проблемы:**

- Значение `var progress`, например, в консоль выводится только после выполнения запроса, а не при каждом изменении значения `evt.loaded` (объем загруженной информации).

**Код:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({ 
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                for(var i = 1; i<evt.total; i++){
                    var progress = Math.round(((i/evt.total)*100)*100)/100;
                    //действие, вывод значения прогресса (консоль / контейнер)          
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },         
        type: "POST",
        url: "main_php/result.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //действие (вывод данных на страницу)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Почитайте вот здесь - https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress, цикл в обработчике progress необходимо убрать.
Плюс вы можете отследить прогресс только на загрузку, скачивания информации, а в то время которое сервер тратит на обработку запроса отследить progress не получится, придётся импровизировать.

Comment: Именно эту статью и читал + http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Comment: попробуйте поиграться с ob_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

в процентах получить вероятнее всего у вас не получится, но накинуть какую-нибудь анимашку на

```
onsend()
```

и закончить ее на

```
success()
```

Comment: Это понятно, что на событиях beforesend,success, complete можно повесить show / hide какую-нибудь gif-анимацию, эти приёмы я знаю, вопрос именно в "живом" прогресс-баре